# "Filter: progid: dximagetransform.microsoft.pixelate" with a modern browser

Tags: css

In the old Internet Explorer filter property, there was a function called ["Pixelate Filter"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms533016(v%3Dvs.85)).

> Displays the content of the object as squares that take on the average color value of the pixels they replace. This filtered display can be used as a transition.

I would like to apply this same function to modern browsers, web site images, text etc, to every element and its contents.

However, this same feature is not found in the current CSS. How can you do this?

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/tigt/pen/akYqAg

Comment: Yes, I would like to apply that effect to all the content on the website (text, images, diagrams made with CSS, etc).

Comment: Realization with SVG is difficult. Because it is overloaded to capture fonts and CSS.